# questions about dimension of irreducible representation

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Consider a finite group $G$ of order $n$ and $\mathbb{C}G$ its regular module.

Show that

(1) No irreducible representation of $\mathbb{C}G$ has dimension greater than $n/k$ where $k$ is the order of any element in $G$.

(2) Every irreducible representation of $\mathbb{C}D_{2n}$ has dimension 1 or 2.

Also,

(3) Fix an element $g$ of order $k$, consider the map $l_g:\mathbb{C}G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}G$ by $l_{g}(h)=gh$. Show that the eigenvalues of $l_g$ are precisely the k-th roots of unity, each with multiplicity $n/k$.

For (1), I don't know where to begin. But for (2), I tried $D_8$ and the result indeed shows that the dimensions are either 1 or 2. But I don't know how to prove the general result.

For (3), I tried to let $gh=\lambda h$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Then $g^{k}h^k=\lambda^{k}h^{k}$ which gives $(\lambda^{k}-1)h^{k}=0$ since $g$ has order $k$. I guess(?) this shows $\lambda$ is the $k$-th roots of unity. How can I show the multiplicity?

Comment: For (2) you should use (1). For (3) note that since the action of $\langle g\rangle$ on the basis splits it into orbits of size $k$ each, the resulting matrix is block diagonal with $k\times k$ blocks. And each block will have characteristic polynomial $x^k - 1$.

Comment: I think you can use (3) for (1); by considering rather $l_g(h) = hg$. Then the eigenspaces for $l_g$ will be subreprsentations of $\mathbb{C}G$ and their dimension might help for (1)

Comment: For (3), think of $l_g$ as a permutation matrix. The permutation preserves each coset of $\langle g \rangle$, and in fact acts on it by a cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove (1) using Frobenius reciprocity. Let $\chi$ be an irreducible character of $G$ and $H = \langle g \rangle$  a cyclic subgroup, and let $\rho$ be an irreducible constituent of $\chi_H$. Then $H$ is abelian, so $\rho$ has degree $1$, and by Frobenius reciprocity $\chi$ is a constituent of $\rho^G$, which has degree $n/k$, where $k=|g|$.

This argument works for any abelian subgroup of $G$, which gives a stronger result.

Comment: I assume you mean Frobenius rather than quadratic near the end.

Comment: Yes, sign of old age!